# Looping over large List, finding best fitting homologe to gene

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a large List of Genes, i want to look up the homologes for.

I also have a large dataframe with potential homologes. 
The tenth column of this Dataframe inherits a number, describing the fitting. The larger the number, the better.

I am trying to loop over this large List of Genes.

For each unique Gene in the List, i want to select the best fitting homologe gene.

The output should be a dataframe with one line per Gene, describing the best fitting homologe.

Comment: Please provide [example data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/680068).

Answer (score 0):

Tidyverse solution, assuming you have a column with an `gene_id` per gene and the fitting score is in a column called `score`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(gene_id) %>% filter(score == max(score)) %>% ungroup()
```

Comment: This seems like a tidy solution =,D. But whenever i try to load the package into library after installing it, the is the following error. Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’

Comment: @JonasEngelhardt you actually only need the `dplyr` package for that and not the whole tidyverse.